# Looping over first two indices in 4-Dimensional Array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have an np.array that has dimensions 478,533,3,3 (variable is titled "window," generated with NumPy stride tricks sliding window from a larger 2D array). The 478x535 portion of the array is basically an array of 3x3 arrays.
I am interested in iterating over all of the 3x3 arrays to obtain the value (and perform some conditional actions) of the [1,1] index point of each of them. I have tried various combinations of loops, but can't seem to figure out a "for" loop for going through each 3x3 array.

```
window = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(tiff_array, (3,3))
P11 = np.zeros([3,3])

for i,j in window:
    block = window[i,j,:,:]
    if block[1,1]==1:
        if block[1,1]-1==1 and block[1,1]-1==1:
            P11[0,0]=P11[0,0]+1
```

This is some of the quick code I've tried in various attempts. I continue to get the error that "there are too many values to unpack" and that two were expected (for i,j I suppose). I know that there are than two values, which is why I'm trying to iterate over each 3x3 array blocks. I think I'm missing something obvious, but would love some help.
TIA!

Comment: Your conditions inside the loop are exclusive `block[1,1]==1` and `block[1,1]-1==1` cannot be simultaneously right. Other wise I suggest flattening the last two axes and using `np.apply_along_axis`. Please tell us exactly what you want to run over your 3x3 blocks and we can help.

Comment: `for i,j in window` is not how you get indexing values that you use like `window[i,j,]`  You need a `for i in range(478)` and a `for j` loop. However this kind of iteration on a `sliding window` feels totally wrong.

Comment: @Learningisamess thanks for the comment. I am basically trying compute 2-point correlations from my original 2D array (480x535). The values in the original array are either 1,2, or 3. So I am trying to take 3x3 blocks of the array, and if the middle of the block is a certain value, figure out what the surrounding values are, and step in increments of 1 to make a new 3x3 block once the values are known. So the middle of first block is the [1,1] index of the original array, and the next block would be the [1,2] index, etc. Let me know if that wasn't clear enough and I can try again.

Comment: @hpaulj I agree, I am trying to avoid using too many nested loops on this, but I might even be wrong to use the sliding window. My above comment kind of clarifies my goal...a picture tends to provide a better representation of what I'm trying to accomplish, but I don't think I can add a picture to the comments.

Comment: If you have to work separately on each (3,3) it doesn't matter whether you iterate with 2 nested loops or one flattened `478*533` one. Or hide the interations in `apply_along...`.  Same numbrr of inner most calls.

Comment: We need a [mcve], for example with a toy (10,10) tiffarray

Comment: What's `block[1,1]-1==1` supposed to be?  Assuming `window[i,j]` was right, and `block[1,1]==1`, then `block[1,1]=1` will be 0, never 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach works with the following changes:

```
window = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(tiff_array, (3,3))
P11 = np.zeros([3,3])

for block in window.reshape(-1, 3, 3):
    if block[1,1]==1:
        if block[1,1]-1==1 and block[1,1]-1==1:
            P11[0,0]=P11[0,0]+1
```

I don't know what you really need to do, but a vectorized approach in this style is usually better:

```
t11 = tiff_array[1:-1, 1:-1]
ones = t11 == 1
P11[0, 0] = ones.sum()
...
```

`t11` is only a view into the original array, so it doesn't spend additional memory.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I'm looking for - views of 3x3 blocks into the original master "tiff_array." I am trying to determine the center value of every 3x3 block in the array, perform some conditional calculations between the center and the perimeter values, and then move in a step of one to the next 3x3 block in snake-like fashion across the entire array. So the first block would have its center at [1,1], the next at [1,2] all the way to a center at [478,533].

Comment: Be careful when doing a `reshape` on a sliding window view.  It tends to blow up memory use.

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to show how it could work. I'm not a very big fan of sliding_window_view myself.

Answer (score 0):

For a smaller starting array:

```
In [17]: arr = np.random.randint(1,4,(6,6))    
In [18]: arr
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1],
       [3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1]])

In [19]: window = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, (3,3))    
In [20]: window.shape
Out[20]: (4, 4, 3, 3)
```

The centers:

```
In [21]: window[:,:,1,1]
Out[21]: 
array([[2, 3, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3]])
```

counting them is easy:

```
In [22]: (window[:,:,1,1]==1).sum()
Out[22]: 3
```

As commented I don't know what you are summing.

But lets take a guess, at least to see how iterating on the blocks should work:

```
In [26]: P=np.zeros((3,3),int)
In [27]: for i in range(window.shape[0]):
    ...:     for j in range(window.shape[1]):
    ...:         block = window[i,j]
    ...:         if block[1,1]==1:
    ...:             print(block[0,1],block[2,1])
    ...:             P += block
    ...:             
2 1
1 1
1 3

In [28]: P
Out[28]: 
array([[7, 4, 3],
       [8, 3, 3],
       [8, 5, 3]])
```

Squinting and looking sideways, I almost can imagine

```
 if block[1,1]==1:
    if block[1,1]-1==1 and block[1,1]-1==1:
```

just means

```
block[1,1]==1 and block[1,0]==1 and block[1,2]==1
(block[1,:]==1).all()
```

that is, just the whole row of each block is 1

```
In [66]: P=np.zeros((3,3),int)
    ...: for i in range(window.shape[0]):
    ...:     for j in range(window.shape[1]):
    ...:         block = window[i,j]
    ...:         if (block[1,:]==1).all():
    ...:             P[:] += block
    ...: P            
Out[66]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

In my small sample there aren't any size 3 sequences of 1s.